# Gnome Shell without the application dashboard (like Unity)

Tags: unity, 11.10, gnome

I've just installed `gnome-themes-default` and enabled `gnome-shell` on my **Ubuntu 11.10** but I can't see those fancy windows/application dashboards (of Gnome 3) like Unity had.

[image]

Can someone tell me what to do or install? Maybe some problem with **lightdm** or **gdm**?

Comment: No problems with lightdm or gdm

Answer (score 2):

That is not Gnome Shell, but Gnome Panel 3. It is provided by Gnome Shell as a fallback, since it cannot be used on all hardware. If you get that when you select Gnome Shell, that means you cannot use Gnome Shell, for some reason. Perhaps your hardware can't handle it, or maybe you need to install a driver for your VGA. There is no Gnome Shell equivalent to Unity 2D.

Comment: I'm installing the ATI/AMD FGLRX drivers right now.. i'll let you know if it worked, thanks for the reply :)